# Linq filter out rows with null or string.empty

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a linq query where I am reading  all the lines of a CSV the file has extra rows at the end that have no data. I need to filter out those rows so that  it only has the rows with data
I am using the following query but it still returns like 8000 rows and there are only 52 with data in them.

```
   var query =
            from c in
                (from line in File.ReadAllLines(excelFile)
                    let transactionRecord = line.Split(',')
                    select new Transaction()
                    {
                        TxnId = transactionRecord[12],

                    })
            where c.TxnTax != string.Empty
            select c;
```

Not relaly sure why this is happening? Doe anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you show some example data? Difficult to know what's wrong without it.

Comment: Where is TxnTax being assigned? It looks like you've got an IEnumerable<Transaction> with TxnId assigned that you are iterating through, but I don't see where you assign TxnTax anywhere. It could be a null value.

Comment: maybe `from line in File.ReadAllLines(excelFile) where !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line)`

Comment: Are you actually even setting `c.TxnTax`? If not, then it will be `null` for all results anyway, so no point testing that. I believe my other comment is the solution anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked

```
var query =
                    from c in
                        (from line in File.ReadAllLines(excelFile)
                            let transactionRecord = line.Split(',')
                            select new Transaction()
                            {
                                TxnId = transactionRecord[12],

                            })
                    where ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.TxnId) == false) && (c.TxnId != "Billing Information|Transaction ID"))
                    select c;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give an `IEnumerable` containing the lines (`string[]`) having at least one column with data

```
IEnumerable<string[]> data = 
    from line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("")
    let lineData = line.Split(',')
    where lineData.Any(cell => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell))
    select lineData;
```